# how to we compress large size payloads into kinesis Streams?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, gzip, amazon-kinesis, payload

i have a JSON payload of 5 MB which i need to push to Kinesis streams using put records. Since the Kinesis data size limit is 1 MB, which methods i should follow to compress the data and what will be the steps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your json payload is still too big after compression, then you have generally **two options**:

1. **Split** it into multiple smaller payloads. The consumers would have to be able to reconstruct the payloads based on a `part id` of your payload.
2. **Store** the large payload data outside of the stream, e.g. in S3, and just send metadata of the large file (e.g. s3 path) in the messages.

Which compression to use is dependent on your stream producer. More specifically,  which compression algorithms do they support.

But ultimately if either of the two options is not suited for you, then you may need to consider that the Kinesis is not the right tool for the job. I think Apache Kafka can support larger messages than 1MB.

Comment: And do remember to delete the object from S3 when no longer required. Depending on amount of data that you are keeping in S3, cost can increase very quickly, very fast.