# how can i compress a larger data (5MB JSON) and sending to Kinesis stream as producer and decompress it while consuming it?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, gzip, producer-consumer, amazon-kinesis

i have a requirement like this :

```
there is payload which is sizing up to 5MB or +
we need to compress this data and then pushed the compressed data to Kinesis
after pushing this data, when we consume this, we need to decompress it...
```

my client asking me to use all available methods for the compression and select the best ones. interestingly  I am very new to this and do not know what to do. i never heard of this before. I am using python code for producing the data.

if anyone has any experience doing it before, please share your thoughts or guide me?

Note : i could see many points to use S3 for storing data but client doesn't need that method

Comment: This is basically just a copy-and-paste of [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786731/how-to-we-compress-large-size-payloads-into-kinesis-streams), so I'm not sure why you expect something other than a copy-and-paste answer.

Comment: yes correct. But my i should not use S3 or split the files. thats why asked the question again and clearly mentioned i can use S3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use GZIP to compress JSON data in python program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62887366/how-to-use-gzip-to-compress-json-data-in-python-program)

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to solve your problem:

1. Split it into multiple smaller payloads. The consumers would have to be able to reconstruct the payloads based on a part id of your payload.
2. Store the large payload data outside of the stream, e.g. in S3, and just send metadata of the large file (e.g. s3 path) in the messages.

But ultimately if either of the two options is not suited for you, then you may need to consider that the Kinesis is not the right tool for the job. I think Apache Kafka can support larger messages than 1MB.

Comment: i see this answer is just a copy paste  but not giving exact solution